# How to sum $\sum_{x=0}^{N-1} \cos{\left( \frac{2\pi x}{N} \right)}^{2}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, geometric-progressions

I've tried solving it, but I'm not familiar with these kind of progressions and I couldn't get to a result. Also, I've found that the result is just $N/2$, but I don't get why would that be the answer, as it doesn't work for $N=1$ or $N=2$.

Appreciate your help :)

Comment: It works for $N\geq 3$. Hint: use the fact that for real $z$, $$
\cos ^2 z = \frac{{1 + \cos (2z)}}{2} = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\Re e^{2iz}
$$ and the formula for the sum of a geometric progression.

Comment: The above works for finite $N$; my answer doesn't tell you how to compute the sum, but will provide some evidence as to wy the result is $N/2$, by showing that $\lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} \cos^2 \frac{2\pi k}{N} = \frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum_{x=0}^{N-1} \cos^2{\left( \frac{2\pi x}{N} \right)}=\sum_{x=0}^{N-1} 
\frac{1+\cos\left( \frac{4\pi x}{N}\right)}{2}
=\boxed{\frac N2}+\frac12\sum_{x=0}^{N-1}\cos\left( \frac{4\pi x}{N}\right)\tag1$$

Now let compute the latter sum:
$$
\sum_{x=0}^{N-1}\cos\left( \frac{4\pi x}{N}\right)=
\operatorname{Re}\sum_{x=0}^{N-1}\exp\left( \frac{4\pi x}{N}i\right)
=\operatorname{Re}\frac{1-\exp\left(4\pi i\right)}{1-\exp\left(\frac{4\pi}{N}i\right)}=0,\tag2
$$
where we applied the formula for the sum of geometric progression.

Observe that the last equality is valid only for $N>2$, since for $N=1,2$ the denominator degenerates to $0$.
More generally
$$\sum_{x=0}^{N-1}\exp\left( \frac{2K\pi x}{N}i\right)=0$$
for all $N $ except for the divisors of $K $.

Answer (score 2):

*Not for finite $N$, but a cute and fast way to see that asymptotically the result is true, and thus gives a simple sanity check as to "why [that] would be the answer."*

If you are familiar with Riemann sums: you can write
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{N-1} \cos\!\left(\frac{2\pi k}{N}\right)^2= 
N\cdot \frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=0}^{N-1} \cos\!\left(\frac{2\pi k}{N}\right)^2
=N\cdot \frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=0}^{N-1} f\!\left(\frac{k}{N}\right)
$$
for $f\colon[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = \cos(2\pi x)^2$. Now, under mild assumptions easy to check here, you get
$$
\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=0}^{N-1} f\!\left(\frac{k}{N}\right) \xrightarrow[N\to\infty]{} \int_0^1 f(x)dx
$$
so you just need to compute
$$
\int_0^1 \cos(2\pi x)^2dx = \frac{1}{2}.
$$

---

*This last part follows from (1) $
\int_0^1 \cos(2\pi x)^2dx + \int_0^1 \sin(2\pi x)^2dx = 1
$ (since $\cos^2+\sin^2=1$)
and (2) $\int_0^1 \cos(2\pi x)^2dx = \int_0^1 \sin(2\pi x)^2 dx $ (e.g., via integration by parts).*